# Screen navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, search, navigation

**Update:**

The app has two stateful widget screens: Home, and Search. Both screens have search boxes and a bottom navigation.

The problem that needs to be solved is when a user taps the **search box at the top of the home screen**, the app should take them to the **search screen without hiding the bottom navigation** (just like what the eBay app does).

I have tried calling the Search class when the user taps the search box on the Home screen. And this approach works. However, the new screen hides the navigation bar at the bottom.

The following code handles the navigation between screens.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
          key: _navigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case 'Search':
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Search());
              default:
                return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserHome());
            }
          }),
       bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home),title: Text('Home'))
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(int tappedIndex) {
    setState(() => _currentIndex = tappedIndex);
    switch (tappedIndex) {
      case 0:
        _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('Home');
        break;
      case 1:
        _navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed('Search');
        break;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Just call a function

Comment: can you send code?

Comment: @JideGuru, could you explain further?

Comment: @Haryanvi, please see the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this for automated testing. You can do so using widget testing. Widget tests in flutter can simulate button taps and check for the expected output

---

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPageState createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  bool home;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    home = true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: home ? UserHome() : Search(),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: _onTap,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text('Search'))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap(int tappedIndex) {
    setState(() {
      if (tappedIndex == 0) {
        home = true;
      } else {
        home = false;
      }
    });
  }
}

class UserHome extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Text('USER HOME'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class Search extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text('SEARCH'),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I know this is not exactly very similar to your initial solution but it achieves the behavior you intend.

Comment: No, it's not for testing. The question has been updated. Could you give it a second look?

Comment: could you please explain where exactly / why you would need to “press” the button programtically

Comment: If a users taps the search or home icon on the navigation bar, they can easily navigate between the two screens while keeping the bottom navigation visible. 

As I tried to explain in the question, there's a search box on the home page and when a users taps on the box, the app should taken them to the search page. I was able to implement this but the the search page takes the whole screen, hiding the navigation bar at the bottom. The goal is to navigate to the search page without hiding the navigation bar. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But tapping on a search box that is found in the UserHome class and navigating to the TestPage still remains unsolved.

Comment: Would you mind including the code for the search box